# What causes padding to alter layout of absolutely positioned div?

Tags: css, html, layout, css-position

On this website: [www.giftlab.com](http://www.giftlab.com)

The "Free Shipping" circle at the top (div id: `floating-header-button`) has `position: absolute; top: 10px`. Its parent div (`headerContainer`) has style `position: relative; padding: 1px;`

If the padding of the parent div (`headerContainer`) is changed from 1px, to 0px, the child div (`floating-header-button`) drops down the page by about 20px. What causes this? How can a 1px change to the padding produce a 20px change to the positioning?

If I *increase* the padding, the circle stays where it is and everything else moves (as I would expect), so why does reducing the padding below 1px produce such a counterintuitive effect?

Comment: Probably margin collapse.

Answer (score 2):

Without the padding on the `.headerContainer`, a margin on a sub-element (`.logo` specifically) [collapses](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) with `.headerContainer`, bumping the entire container down by its margin which is `20px`.